# ENS refinement before deployment (Swaldman catch)

Tags: solidity, security, ens

User @Swaldman made a great catch today and found a bug in ENS auction code:

https://github.com/ethereum/ens/issues/49

What are the various ways to fix/prevent this attack vector before deployment?

Comment: Without reading all of the details (or trying to understand it) - change `_value` to `actualValue` in those 3 places? :-)

Answer (score 1):

The fix is in https://github.com/ethereum/ens/pull/51/files and is as described by the comment by @Richard Horrocks: change `_value` to `actualValue`

For example:

```
} else if (_value > h.value) {
```

should be:

```
} else if (actualValue > h.value) {
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. :P